# PHP: Split an odd number into three groups

Tags: php

I'm counting the number of elements in a section and it's an **even number** like 34, I would like to split them into three logical groups, like:

- Group 1: 1 to 12 (12 items)
- Group 2: 13-24 (12 items)
- Group 3: 25-34 (10 items)

I want the PHP code to logically create three groups of items where the first two sets can hold equal number of items and the rest can go into the last set. **There won't be more than three sets.**

```
$whole_elements=33;
$group1 = ($whole_elements) / 3;
```

This kind of code would not work as it would return a value with decimal point.

Comment: what happened to `21`? shouldn't it be `21-30` then the next should be `31-33`?

Comment: its still weird, if you're going to cut it by ten's then shouldn't it be `1-10, 11-20, 21-30, 31-33` so all in all 4 groups. group3 should be `21-30 (10 items)`

Comment: What if `whole_elements` is 25 ? you want 10 + 10 + 5 or 8 + 8 + 9 or 9 + 9 + 7 ? Btw, to downvoters, I think it's an interesting question but terribly formulated

Comment: I'm talking about odd number only. I want the PHP code to logically create three groups of items where the first two sets can hold equal number of items and the rest can go into the last set. There won't be more than three sets.

Comment: @Capsule let me know if it's not clear and I need to edit the question.

Comment: You have 33 numbers, but only 29 in your three groups, what happened to the other 4 MIA?

Comment: I'm terribly sorry for the mistakes in the question. I didn't count the number well. Have updated it.

Comment: You don't know what you want. Do you want to limit it by the number of groups, or by the fact that something's an odd number, or the count of units in a group? Your problem is a lack of thinking, not of programming skills. However I encourage you to look at floor(), ceil() and round().

Comment: @joshstrike what's the problem now? I said it can be any number. I have mentioned the logic behind the grouping method and the number maximum groups there will be.

Answer (score 1):

You should divide your number by 3, round the result to obtain the first 2 numbers, then use a modulo to get the last one:

```
<?php
$whole_elements=34;
$group1 = $group2 = round($whole_elements / 3);
$group3 = $whole_elements % $group1;
?>
```

Then obtaining the "groups" is a matter of slicing the original array:

```
<?php
$group1_array = array_slice($original_array, 0, $group1);
$group2_array = array_slice($original_array, $group1, $group1);
$group3_array = array_slice($original_array, -$group3);
?>
```

In fact, using this method, you don't need to determine `$group2` in the first bit of code as it's the same as `$group1`

Answer (score 0):

```
$whole_elements = 34;

$third = ceil($whole_elements / 3);
$group1 = $group2 = $third;
$group3 = $whole_elements - 2*$third;
echo 'one: ' . $group1 . '<br/>two: ' . $group2 . '<br/>three: ' . $group3;
```

> one: 12
>   two: 12
>   three: 10